# What is an appropriate value of the parameter "Size" in nnet function in R?

Tags: neural-network, hyperparameters, nnet

I read somewhere that is should be which.is.max of the nnet model. Is there a rule of thumb to define the value for Size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, a single appropriate `size` hyperparameter does not exist. This value (as well as weight `decay`) depends on the data and the application at hand. Cross-validation procedures may provide you with decent values for a specific dataset. You should try Random search or Grid Search, which are two basic (yet effective) approaches to this problem. I also recommend you to check this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw) about how to choose the number of hidden layers and nodes in a feedforward neural network.